# how to add a custom button(for inserting image) in the toolbar of HtmlEditorExtender

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

i am using HtmlEditorExtender in AjaxControlToolkit... HtmlEditor may also be ok.

I found a similar sample for HtmlEditor here

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/OtherSamples/EditorWithCustomButtons_1.aspx

but where is the source code? ... even with the source code, i am not sure whether it is hard to insert images in an editor...

please help! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLEditor is created and managed by OBOUT. Have a look at their documentation on how to do this:
http://www.obout.com/editor_new/sample_ImageBrowse.aspx

If that doesn't help, I would suggest using TinyMCE. Built in javascript and has a lot more features by default.